# Creating community user through apex

Tags: apex, community, force.com-sites, administration

[image: Site Config Screenshot]

I am facing following error while creating user through `Apex`:

> 'The site is not enabled for registration.'

Can any one help me out?

Comment: Have you checked the login settings. Login must be enabled there. When you go to your site detail page, you will see a button for "login settings" besides "public access settings". Click on login settings and see if the enable login checkbox has been checked or not.

Comment: I am unable to find that button in site detail page..could you help me out?

Comment: can you click on custom url seciton login settings ?

Comment: Yes, but its redirtecting to Login & Registration Section of Communities

Comment: I am not able to see the apex code or the error. Can you please post the correct screen?